# How do I calculate the function representation of the function?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

How do I alculate the function representation of the function $\frac{z^3+4z}{z^2-4}$ with $z_0=1$?

*What I have done:*

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty } (z-a)^k=\frac1{1-(z-a)},\qquad |z-a|<1,
$$

$$\frac{z^3+4z}{z^2-4}=z+\frac{4}{z-2}+\frac{4}{z+2}$$

$$\frac{4}{z+2}=\frac{2}{z/2+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(z/2)^k$$
$$\frac{4}{z-2}=\frac{4}{1-(-z-1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-z-1)^k$$

What is next that I should do?

Comment: First series has $|z|<2$ for convergence radius and the last has $|z+1|<1$ so the intersection of them is $|z+1|<1$  as  convergence region.

Answer (score 0):

First write it centered on $z_0=1$,
$$\begin {align}\frac{z^3+4z}{z^2-4}&=\frac {((z-1)+1)^3+4(z-1+1)}{(z-1+1)^2-4}
 \\ &=\frac{(z-1)^3+3(z-1)^2+7(z-1)+5}{(z-1)^2+2(z-1)-3}\\
&=(z-1)+1+\frac 4{(z-1)-1}+\frac 4{(z-1)+3}
\end{align}$$
and you should know series for the last two terms.